# Typescript NodeJs solution split into multiple projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, architecture, projects-and-solutions

I want to develop a typescript nodejs solution split into 3 sub project like a csharp solution split into multiple libraries.

I want that each of them has its own `pacakge.json`

- UI project
  `package.json`
- Infrastructure
  `package.json`
- Domain
  `package.json`

Obviously, I want from one project to reference another, for example, `ui` can reference the `infrastructure` project

In the `package.json` I found to reference another package using the syntax `file:`:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "infrastrucure": "file:../infrastructure"
  },
```

The main drawbacks I found:

- Compile the dependant projects before running the `ui`
- The eslint show a warning

> Cannot read file on `<solution root>\tsconfig.json`

What I want to know is:

1. This is the correct approach to split into multiple projects a solution or there are more not considered drawbacks?
2. Why eslint looking for tsconfig.json into the root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found [Rush](https://rushjs.io/) a *monorepos* tool by Microsoft.
This tool (for me) is the most similar to a .sln like visual studio and uses the [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/), the package manager that I already use.

Answer (score 1):

[lerna](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna) or [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) can help you manage a multi-project repository in the way you have described. I'm not sure how to fix your errors without seeing how eslint is setup, but it might be worth looking into these solutions instead of trying to set everything up yourself.

Comment: Have you experienced one (or both) of them? Lerna seems to be more complex rather than yarn. What is your _honest_ opinion?

Comment: I've only used `lerna` personally and haven't used it in great depth, but I found it a bit clunky although it does the job. Yarn workspaces is newer and I've heard good things from others about it but have never tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, Christos